# The way to solve cpu load too high of Java application

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jstack

Today, I found the cpu of load of my server is too high，and the server is just running a Java application.

Here are my operation steps.

1. I used `top` command to find the application's pid. The pid is 25713.
2. I used `top -H -p 25713` command to find some pids which used the most of cpu. Such as `25719 tomcat    20   0 10.6g 1.5g  13m R 97.8  4.7 314:35.22 java`.
3. I used `jstack -F 25713` command to print the dump info.Such as `"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5f10021800 nid=0x6477 runnable`
4. I searched the pid from the dump file. Then I found that the pids which used most of cpu are all like `"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5f10021800 nid=0x6477 runnable`
5. After I used the `jstack` command, then the cpu became normal!

Here are my questions:

1. Why `GC Threads` made the cpu load too high.
2. Why after I used `jstack` command the cpu became nomal.

More than this time, every time.

Here are some normal logs.`2015-10-10T10:17:52.019+0800: 71128.973: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:17:52.019+0800: 71128.973: [ParNew: 309991K->206K(348416K), 0.0051145 secs] 616178K->306393K(1009920K), 0.0052406 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]`

When the CPU comes too high, the GC log stay in `[GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:18:10.564+0800: 71147.518: [ParNew:`, and there is no other logs.

When I execute `jstack` command, the log printed

```
2015-10-10T10:17:50.757+0800: 53501.137: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:17:50.757+0800: 53501.137: [ParNew: 210022K->245K(235968K), 369.6907808 secs] 400188K->1
90410K(1022400K), 369.6909604 secs] [Times: user=3475.15 sys=11.69, real=369.63 secs]
```

Comment: For Java 7 switching off parallel GC did the trick: `-XX:-UseParallelGC`.

Comment: @rsutormin - Voodoo GC tuning ....

Comment: what operating system, java version and CPU do you use? And do I understand you correctly that the process is stuck in a GC until you use `jstack -F`?

Comment: @the8472,`Linux version 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64`,`32  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz`,`jdk1.8.0_60`. 

Yes,my application resume normal until i use `jstack -F`

Comment: @StephenC - yep, but original problem of such behavior is I guess that program produces huge amount of small objects and throws them away soon with high speed. So I would think about optimization related to reusing already created objects rather than making new ones.

Comment: So would turning off the parallel GC help?  Basically, you have propose a cause with no supporting evidence, then proposed a solution with no rationale ... that doesn't seem to address your proposed solution.  Voodoo :-)

Comment: No, I just said that non-parallel GC works longer but doesn't eat more than one core. Parallel one can eat all cores you have. It helps to eliminate only consequences. But real cause is (my guess) what I said in prev. comment.

Comment: Weirdly enough, if it is the `futex_wait` bug that is causing it, switching off parallel GC might indeed conceivably work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just guessing, you *might* be affected by the [futex_wait bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64) present in certain kernel versions.

More generally, `jstack -F` sends a signal to the process, which will interrupt any thread that may be sleeping. So maybe GC threads just spin-waiting for another thread that somehow missed a wakeup. I.e. if it's indeed stuck in a GC and sending a signal fixes the problem then this may point to a locking or memory ordering bug, if not in the kernel then in the JVM.

Instead of using `jstack -F` you could try sending `SIGBREAK` to the process and see if that has the same effect.

Comment: How i send `SIGBREAK` to the process. Give an example?

Comment: There are other java applications on the server,but they are find..For help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: It is not a system bug.If i deploy the application on other server,also has the same problem..so .

Comment: then maybe you should see if there are any difference between the servers, the JVM versions or the JVM flags (`-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`). Or if your system experiences load spikes due to the other JVMs (swapping, IO, CPU load)

Comment: Thank you,But my linux kernel version is `2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64`,and possibly because of the bug??

Comment: centos version is `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`

Comment: you have `2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64`, the fix is in is in `kernel-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6` (note the 16.2). So yes, you're within the window of affected kernel versions. All you had to do is read the the mailing list thread I have linked, all the information is there.

Answer (score 0):

> why GC Threads made the cpu load too high.

Your JVM was probably running a full GC.  And since your JVM is probably running with a huge heap (hinted by the 10.6 Gigabyte memory size), that is going to take a long time.  It is also possible that your system is thrashing virtual memory.

> why after i used jstack command the cpu became nomal.

Coincidence ... probably.  The GC finished while you were running jstack.

---

If you want to investigate this, I suggest that you turn on garbage collection logging, and try to correlate the periods of high CPU load with the GC activity.

The other thing that the GC logs should tell you is whether your Tomcat's heap is too full.  If your webapps have memory leaks, then that will cause the heap to fill up with objects that cannot be garbage collected.  In time, that will lead to the JVM spending more and more time running the GC.  If that is the problem, then you need to find and fix the memory leaks.

Comment: The last GC log printed  `2015-10-10T10:17:50.757+0800: 53501.137: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:17:50.757+0800: 53501.137: [ParNew: 210022K->245K(235968K), 369.6907808 secs] 400188K->1
90410K(1022400K), 369.6909604 secs] [Times: user=3475.15 sys=11.69, real=369.63 secs]`

Comment: That doesn't look like a "full heap" / "memory leak" problem.  However, I'm not a GC tuning expert.  I suggest you cut-paste more of the GC logs and also your JVM's GC switches into the question ... and hope that someone else can help you.