# The java application feign death. Jstack can make application recovery?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jstack

Today i found that my application could not be accessed.Then i login in my server.I found that the application's thread was normal,But the CPU load was too high.

Then,i wanted to use `jstack` command.But it pointed out `need -F option`.And now i found the GC log stay in `[GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:18:10.564+0800: 71147.518: [ParNew:`, and there is no other logs.

Then,i used `jstack -F` command.Strange things happened.The CPU became normal,and my server also became normal,and The GC log also nomal,and the first line was `[GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:17:50.757+0800: 53501.137: [ParNew: 210022K->245K(235968K), 369.6907808 secs] 400188K->1
90410K(1022400K), 369.6909604 secs] [Times: user=3475.15 sys=11.69, real=369.63 secs]`.And the jstack's result's runnable thread were all GC thread,like `"Gang worker#4 (Parallel GC Threads)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5f10021800 nid=0x6477 runnable`

Here are my JAVA_OPTIONS

> -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
>     -Xms2g -Xmx2g -Xmn512m \
>     -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 \
>     -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 \
>     -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/data/logs/gc-skynetlog_web.log \
>     -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M \
>     -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/data/logs/dump_skynetlog_web.hprof

Comment: It is unlikely that `jstack` fixed anything.  It is more likely that your JVM was taking a ling time doing a full GC, and that finished while you were running `jstack`.  Just a coincidence.

Comment: s/ling/long/p .... (ed)

Comment: isn't that pretty much the same question you already asked in http://stackoverflow.com/q/33049375/1362755 ?

Comment: @StephenC,not a coincidence,every time. For help.

Comment: @the8472,sorry,No one gave the correct answer, in a way to ask the next question.

Comment: @StephenC,not only jstack,jmap also can make the application normal..Made me confused!

Comment: @DevZhou well, looking at the source code here (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/jvm/hotspot/bugspot/BugSpotAgent.java#608). It seems jstack does able to suspend the thread) which running the minor gc (which might be the cause of the application hang as it takes a long time).

Comment: @kucing_terbang,excuse me, how can I do now.How to troubleshoot the cause?  Need help,thank you.

Comment: @DevZhou without the source code and how the application works. It seems not possible for me to detect the cause. you might want to check this article (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/hangloop.html) and see whether there is something that could help you. :)

Comment: @kucing_terbang,with your experience,which reason might be the cause of the minor gc hang.when the application hang,the gc log stay in `[GC (Allocation Failure) 2015-10-10T10:18:10.564+0800: 71147.518: [ParNew:` until i execute the `jstack` command.  Thand you.

Comment: @DevZhou I'm also not so sure about the reason. As, usually, in my experience, minor gc usually only take around 1 sec max. Try to use the parallel gc (-XX:+UseParallelGC) and see whether this gc type able to make the operation faster.

Comment: @kucing_terbang,Produce a large number of new object by doing minor gc  might be the cause of question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92068/discussion-between-dev-zhou-and-kucing-terbang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fresh bug affecting Linux kernels 3.14 - 3.18

Symptoms, thread is consuming 100% while blocking on synchronization primitive. Sending signal (like jstack -F does) is fixing this situation.
In case of JVM, if GC thread is affect by this, application will stay in STW pause forever.

You can find more details in [this post by Gil Tene](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mechanical-sympathy/QbmpZxp6C64)

Comment: I already provided the same answer in the question I linked in the comments. OP says the provided answers weren't "correct"

Comment: Thank you,But my linux kernel version is `2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64`,and possibly because of the bug??

Comment: centos version is `CentOS release 6.7 (Final)`